# Refresh ColdFusion application from a shell script

Tags: coldfusion

How can I refresh a ColdFusion 11 application (REST services) from a command line? I know it is possible from the admin interface by pressing the "Refresh" button, but in this case I have to script it somehow.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by refresh? clear all cache? re-init ORM? restart service?

Comment: After I modify the code, in order for the changes to be applied I need to go to the admin interface > Data & Services > REST Services and there is the list of active REST services. There is a "Actions" column in the table with 3 buttons, one of which is "Refresh". I need to press it to apply my changes to the app. It's like some kind of compilation I guess? I don't know much about CF, just working with some legacy code.

Comment: I imagine the admin API could be used to programmatically handle that for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Scott, you pointed me in the right direction. The admin API is poorly documented but I was able to figure it out. I created the following script that can later be called from command line with with CURL:

`<cfscript>
    createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.administrator").login("mypassword");
    exts = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.extensions");
    exts.refreshRESTService("/path/to/the/service");
    WriteOutput("Refreshed");
</cfscript>`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find some documentation on the admin API regarding REST services.

[Getting started with RESTful web services in ColdFusion](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/restful-web-services.html)

About a third way down that page, under the section *Registering a REST application using ColdFusion Admin API*, it mentions the following:

> **Registering a REST application using ColdFusion Admin API:**
>   You can use functions defined in `CFIDE.adminapi.extensions` CFC to manage a REST application. These functions are:
>
> 1. `registerRESTService(rootPath, [service mapping])` : This function registers the REST application. The rootPath specifies the directory containing REST-enabled CFCs. Optionally the service mapping for the REST application can also be specified.
> 2. `getRESTServices()` : This function returns an array of REST services registered with the ColdFusion Administrator.
> 3. `deleteRESTService(rootPath)` : This function deletes the specified REST application registered with ColdFusion Administrator.
> 4. `refreshRESTService(rootPath)` : If you make any changes to the REST-enabled CFCs, you can refresh the registered application by calling this function.
>
> **Registering a REST application using the restInitApplication method:**
>   The above methods described how you can register a REST application in ColdFusion Administrator using the Admin API and Administrator console. Both of these require Administrator privileges to register an application. You can also register a REST application by calling the method restInitApplication and it doesn't require Administrator privileges. The syntax is as follows:
>
> `restInitApplication(rootPath,[serviceMapping])`
>
> If you have already registered the application with the Administrator, a call to restInitApplication refreshes the REST service.
>
> It is also possible to delete the REST service by calling the restDeleteApplication function. The syntax is as follows:
>
> `restDeleteApplication(rootPath)`